# Azure Data Factory check file name dynamically

Tags: azure-data-factory

I'm checking daily if certain files exist in a folder on-prem. The files have a specific format, but the first few letters indicate specific job. For example, xyz-yyyyMMdd.csv, or abc-yyMMdd.csv etc

I would like to use switch activity to see if the file for each job has arrived or an alert should be used. How can I dynamically let the switch activity read the 'xyz' portion knowing that the other part of the file name is dynamic?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If number of your few letters is three as you said, you can try this expression:

```
@substring(item().name,0,3)
```

If no, you can try this:

```
@split(item().name,'-')[0]
```

Here is my test:

[image]

[image]

Comment: @substring(item().name,0,3) worked like a charm! Thank you, Steve.